# Git - Discard changes made to branch

Tags: git, branch

I just started a new branch, but I deleted there one too many files. 
How do I reinstate the master and delete the changes in the branch? what is the command? 
Or is it better to just delete the branch and create a new one instead to keep working on a branch before I merge it to the master?

Would `git merge master` do the trick?

Comment: You should read the [basics](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard all changes on your branch, you can do :

```
git reset --hard master
```

That will reset your branch to the same state as as your master, discarding all changes.